# Point http://myip/api/v1 to http://127.0.0.1:5000

Tags: python, linux, deployment, server, apache2

I have a Python API already running as a `systemctl` service on Linux Apache httpd2 server at http://127.0.0.1:5000 . I need to type on browser http://myserverip/api/v1 to consume it. How could I make it?

I've been searching along too many sites, even try something like this with not success

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /api/v1 http://127.0.0.1:5000
    ProxyPassReverse /api/v1 http://127.0.0.1:5000
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/api-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/api-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I quit this method, for those who need to accomplish that one way (the way I used it) was to tell the app to run on host=ip.

I mean, instead of:

```
app.run(port=5000)
```

Use:

```
app.run(host="#.#.#.#")
```

Where `#.#.#.#` will be the IP, and the service will run on `http://#.#.#.#:5000`